# Vue component method behaving weirdly - loader animation not working while data is processing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, reactive-programming

I'm trying to figure out why this happens - loader for long processing of data does not show.. only after the processing is done. Huge (few thousands items) object of key-value items and want them to make filterable - that works - but takes few seconds. I'm using VueJS 2.

I wanted to show "please wait" message while it runs, using the `isworking`  value. I have a span with `v-if="isworking"`, defined with value `false` as initial value.

On first line I set the `this.isworking` prop, but instead of seeing the "please wait", the **function hangs for few seconds to do a search, and THEN sets the isworking prop to true** - I tried that by commenting the last `isworking=false` - can't figure out why it waits to change it to true for the huge processing to end.

That `window.deaccent` method is fn to replace all accented characters in string with basic ansii chars, nothing special.

In template, I have a simple:

```
<form @submit="searchmath">
 <span v-if="working">please wait</span>
 <input v-model=...>
 <div v-for="(item,index) in searchmatchitems"> ... </div>
</form>
```

Method in component:

```
    searchmatch: function($event){
      this.isworking = true;
      this.$forceUpdate(); // tried also this, does not help
      $event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();
      try{
        var searchid = window.deaccent(this.search_string.toLowerCase());
        var searchobj = this.cdata;
        let result = Object.keys(this.cdata).filter(function(el,i,c){ 
          var elk = window.deaccent(el).toLowerCase();
          var elv = window.deaccent(searchobj[el]);
          return elk.indexOf(searchid) > -1 || elv.indexOf(searchid) > -1;
        }, searchid);
        this.searchmatchitems = result;
        this.isworking = false;
      } catch(e){ console.log(e); this.isworking = false; return [];}
    }
```

I also tried moving the event.preventDefault() to bottom, just to be sure it does not affect anything, but no luck.

That cdata is a simple key-value object with many props like this, counting about 4000 items

```
data: {
  cdata: {
             "lorem": "aa",
             "ipsum": "bc",
             "dolor": "de",
             ....
         },
  isworking: false,
    ....
}
```

Comment: I see, in your snippet above, that v-if uses "working" instead of "isworking". Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

2 issues here.

First, you use `working` in your template, and `isworking` in your data and code.

Second, your method does not call any async code, so it sets `isworking` to true, does work, and then sets `isworking` to false.  You template will never have a chance to refresh in this case, and the UI will freeze until the method returns.

For instance, if you made an async call to a network endpoint, and then set `isworking` to false in the callback, you would get the results you are expecting.

If you have long running code and wish to prevent the UI from freezing, you will need to use a web worker thread